# DataLabels in Highcharts are outside the container / not showing

Tags: javascript, highcharts, label

I'm drawing a half-donut-pie-chart (using innersize and start-/endAngle). But my datalabels are outside the plot area (below the center point / xAxis) or not showing at all regarding my settings.

---

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: '',
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
                percentageDecimals: 1
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    startAngle: -90,
                    endAngle: 90,
                    center: ['50%', '100%'],
                    size: '140%',
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        //crop: false,
                        //overflow: 'none',
                        //useHTML: true,
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                        },
                        style: {
                            width: '100px' // for line wrap on long dataLabels
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
  series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox and this is very very very long name with some spaces etc.',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 12.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                },
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
        }]
        });
    });

});
```

See here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aZ9VA/21/)

---

Using useHTML: `true, useHTML: true` did not work at all any positive.

Using `useHTML: true` would render the overflowing dataLabels inside the plot, but my long dataLabels disapeared.

So how can I accomplish this having the following things in mind?

- My half-donut should always be at the bottom of my plot area and use
  the space (not be too small).
- It happens that I have long datalabels so defining a style.width seems to do a line-wrap if needed.
- DataLabels should always be above the xAxis and not fall below the bottom of my half-donut.
- DataLabels should always be shown and be outside of the chart using connectors.

Thanks in advance and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like possibly bug, reported here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2630